# Why HTML code is different when parsing site using Jsoup than using browser

Tags: java, web-scraping, css-selectors, jsoup, data-extraction

I am on the website http://www.flashscore.com/nhl/ and I am trying to extract the links of the 'Today's Matches' table.

I am trying it with the following code, but it does not work Can you point out where the mistake is?

```
  final Document page = Jsoup
    .connect("http://d.flashscore.com/x/feed/t_4_200_G2Op923t_1_en_1")
    .cookie("_ga","GA1.2.47011772.1485726144")
    .referrer("http://d.flashscore.com/x/feed/proxy-local")
    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36")
    .header("X-Fsign", "SW9D1eZo")
    .header("X-GeoIP", "1")
    .header("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
    .header("Accept" , "*/*")
    .get();

for (Element game : page.select("table.hockey tr")) {
Elements links = game.getElementsByClass("tr-first stage-finished");
for (Element link : links) {
    String linkHref = link.attr("href");
    String linkText = link.text();
}
 }
```

To try to fix it I started to debug it. It shows that we get the page (althouh we are getting kind of a strange HTML). After that the debugging showed that the for loop does not even start. I was trying to change the page.select("") part to different ones (like getElementByAttribute etc.), but I have just started to learn web scraping, so I need to get familiar with those methods to navigate through a document. How am I supposed to extract this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in comments, this website need to execute some Javascript in order to build that linkable elements.
Jsoup only parse HTML, it doesn't run any JS and you won't see same HTML source if you get from a browser or if you get from `Jsoup`.

You need to get the website as if you were running it on a real browser. You can do that programatically using `WebDriver` and `Firefox`.

I've tried with your example site and works:

**pom.xml**

```
<project>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>test</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>test</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.43.0</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

</project>
```

**App.java**

```
package com.test;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class App {

public static void main( String[] args ) {
    App app = new App();
    List<String> links = app.parseLinks();
    links.forEach(System.out::println);
}

public List<String> parseLinks() {
    try {
        WebDriver driver ;
        // should download geckodriver https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases and set according your local file
        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","C:\\apps\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        String baseUrl = "http://www.flashscore.com/nhl/";

        driver.get(baseUrl);

        return driver.findElement(By.className("hockey"))
                .findElements(By.tagName("tr"))
                .stream()
                .distinct()
                .filter(we -> !we.getAttribute("id").isEmpty())
                .map(we -> createLink(we.getAttribute("id")))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
    }
}

private String createLink(String id) {
    return String.format("http://www.flashscore.com/match/%s/#match-summary", extractId(id));
}

private String extractId(String id) {
    if (id.contains("x_4_")) {
        id = id.replace("x_4_","");
    } else if (id.contains("g_4_")) {
        id = id.replace("g_4_","");
    }

    return id;
}
}
```

Output:

```
http://www.flashscore.com/match/f9MJJI69/#match-summary
http://www.flashscore.com/match/zZCyd0dC/#match-summary
http://www.flashscore.com/match/drEXdts6/#match-summary
http://www.flashscore.com/match/EJOScMRa/#match-summary
http://www.flashscore.com/match/0GKOb2Cg/#match-summary
http://www.flashscore.com/match/6gLKarcm/#match-summary
...
...
```

*PS: Working using Firefox version 32.0 and Selenium 2.43.0. It's a common error to use unsupported version between Selenium and Firefox.*

Comment: Hi @exoddues, thank you very much for you solution, it works like charm. Can you also tell me how is it possible to filter out only those who has the todays' date? So let's says the today's date is the variable      'String date'. I guess I should use '.filter()' somehow.

Comment: At first sight seems that 'Today's matches' are placed inside a div with id="fscountry". One way woulld be for example do a filter that get the tr elements that are inside a div with the id="fscountry". Try using instead of the first two .findElement calls use something like .findElement(By.id("fscountry")).findElements(By.tagName("tr")

Comment: Hi @exoddus, it was a good tip. with "fscountry" it did not work, but with "fs". If you inspect te elements you can see why. In the 'Today's Matches' table there is always two elements with the same id (two lines, the Home team above, Away team below), I changed things like that: ... .collections(toSet())" so I got the same id only once. I don't know if it is a best solution for that, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting wrong address in `.connect("http://d.flashscore.com/x/feed/t_4_200_G2Op923t_1_en_1")` - you need to use `.connect("http://www.flashscore.com/nhl/")` in there.

Then, this site uses JS and after you'll get the right page -it will be rendered differently than in browser, e.g. there won't be a table with class 'hockey'. You'l see it in the page you'll get.
So, you'll need to change locators.
Or consider using `WebDriver` for this.

Comment: you are right, I changed the string in the .connect and now I am getting the right HTML.  thanks. :)  and do you have any idea how am I supposed to write the for loop to extract the links of the games?

Comment: THe results are wrapped into `div id="tournament-page-data-summary-results"` which doesn't contain any links. I don't think it's possible with JSoup. Try using any `WebDriver` impementation like ChromeDriver or FirefoxDriver - which support JS

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WebClient extends WebViewClient {
   TextView tv;
   Activity activity;

   String js = "javascript:setTimeout(function(){"
      + "window.HtmlHandler.handle("
      + "document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]"
      + ".innerHTML);"
      + "},2000);";

   public WebClient (WebView web) {
      web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      web.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
      web.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(false);
      web.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Chrome: 41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36");
      web.addJavascriptInterface(new JsInterface(),"HtmlHandler");
      web.setWebViewClient(this);
   }

   public WebClient setText(Activity activity, TextView tv) {
      this.activity = activity;
      this.tv = tv;
      return this;
   }

   @JavascriptInterface
   @Override
   public void onPageFinished (WebView view, String url) {
      view.loadUrl(js);
   }

   private class JsInterface {
      @JavascriptInterface
      public void handle(String html) {
         activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
               tv.setText(html);
            }
         });
      }
   }
}
```

MainActivity

```
     .....

webView.loadUrl(url);
webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
new WebClient(webView).setText(this,textView);

     .....
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).